# query.onSnapshot() runs twice every time text box changes text on the page - Firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have an input tag: `<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />` (message and setMessage are state variables).

I also have a Firebase query: `firebase.firestore().collection('messages').where('users', 'array-contains', uid)`

I set up a `query.onSnapshot` listener to listen for collection updates, and put a `console.log` inside of it.

It triggers twice every time the text changes in the text box, and I included the entire tag because it doesn't trigger when another input tag, with an `onChange` attribute (but doesn't change a state variable) is changed, so it seems that the problem is somewhere with the state variable.

Does anyone know what might be triggering the `onSnapshot` event?

```
function Chatroom(props) {
  const [ messages, setMessages ] = useState([])
  const [ chatWithUser, setChatWithUser ] = useState("")
  const [ chatWithUserTemp, setChatWithUserTemp ] = useState("")
  const [ message, setMessage ] = useState("")
  
  const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser

  const mref = firestore.collection('messages')
  const query = mref.where('users', 'array-contains', uid).orderBy('time')

  const getContent = async() => {
    let content = []

    await query.get().then((docs) => {
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        if(doc.data().users.includes(chatWithUser)) {
          content.push(<li key={doc.id}>From: {doc.data().sender}, message: {doc.data().message}</li>)
        }
      })
    })

    setMessages(content)
  }

  const updateMessages = (data) => {

  }

  query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    getContent()
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    getContent()
  }, [])

  const sendMessage = () => {
    mref.add({
      message: message,
      sender: auth.currentUser.uid,
      time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      users: [auth.currentUser.uid, chatWithUser]
    })

    setMessage("")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="sidenav">
        <h3>Chat with Users</h3>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter UID" onChange={(e) => setChatWithUserTemp(e.target.value)}></input>
        <Button onClick={() => setChatWithUser(chatWithUserTemp)}>Chat</Button>
        <p>Your UID: {auth.currentUser.uid}</p>
        <Logout />
      </div>

      <div className="main">
        <p>Chatting with {chatWithUser}</p>
        <ul>
          {messages}
        </ul>

        <input type="text" value={message} className="form-control" placeholder="Message..." onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
        <Button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</Button>
      </div>
            
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what might be wrong without seeing the code. Can you post the source code of your component, or include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/arbPDK Please try to excuse the bad code... I'm a beginner with React and JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method call is in the body of the component:

```
  query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    getContent()
  })
```

The component body gets called every time the component rerenders, so this is creating a new subscription to the query every time the component renders.

Since subscribing to a query is a side effect, it should be called inside a useEffect callback:

```
function Chatroom(props) {
  // ...

  // mref is used both inside and outside the effect. useMemo ensures it's only
  // called once so we can add it to the effect's dependency array
  const mref = useMemo(() => firestore.collection("messages"), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // since query and getContent are only used by this effect, we should
    // define them inside the effect so we don't have to worry about
    // adding them to the dependency array

    const query = mref.where("users", "array-contains", uid).orderBy("time");

    const getContent = async () => {
      let content = [];

      await query.get().then((docs) => {
        docs.forEach((doc) => {
          if (doc.data().users.includes(chatWithUser)) {
            content.push(
              <li key={doc.id}>
                From: {doc.data().sender}, message: {doc.data().message}
              </li>
            );
          }
        });
      });

      setMessages(content);
    };

    const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      getContent();
    });

    // Firebase will call the onSnapshot callback once automatically, so there
    // is no need to call getContent outside of onSnapshot

    // When the component is unmounted, we need to unsubscribe from the
    // query so we don't keep getting updates
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [mref]);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    mref.add({
      message: message,
      sender: auth.currentUser.uid,
      time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      users: [auth.currentUser.uid, chatWithUser],
    });

    setMessage("");
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't want to completely rewrite this, but you should consider using the `snapshot` parameter, instead of calling `query.get()` after every update. See the [Firestore documentation for "Listen to multiple documents in a collection"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `query.onSnapshot` function is being triggered in every state update. The general approach with listeners is to put them in lifecycle hooks and then clean them

something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      getContent()
    })
    return () => unsubscribe()
}, [])
```

The return of an useEffect will unsubscribe the listener
you only will call getContent in the onSnapshot , also the snapshot will have your latest messages, so not need to query them again in getContent